# I am getting error unsupported operands \libraries\Pagination.php when i try to put pagenation on result page

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

```
**This is my controller**
$this->load->library("pagination");  
$this->load->helper('url');
$this->load->view('includes/kheader');
$this->load->view('includes/kmenu');

$per_page=$this->input->post('per_page');
$look = $this->input->post('look');
$age = $this->input->post('age'); 
$age_from = $this->input->post('age_from');
$age_to = $this->input->post('age_to');
$se_ct = $this->input->post('sect');
$subsect = $this->input->post('subsect');
$coun_try = $this->input->post('country');
$sta_te = $this->input->post('state');
$ci_ty = $this->input->post('city');
$qualification = $this->input->post('qualification');

        $data['base']=$this->config->item('base_url');
        $data['title']= 'Message form';
        $this->load->model("searchresultss");
     $per_pg=1;
        $offset=$this->uri->segment(2);
        $total=$this->searchresultss->login($per_pg,$offset,$per_page,$look,$age, $age_to,$age_from,$se_ct,$subsect,$coun_try,$sta_te, $ci_ty, $qualification);


        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] = $data['base'].'/searchresult/users/';
        $config['total_rows'] = $total;
        $config['per_page'] = $per_pg;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['pagination']=$this->pagination->create_links();

        $data['query']=$this->searchresultss->login($per_pg,$offset,$per_page,$look,$age, $age_to,$age_from,$se_ct,$subsect,$coun_try,$sta_te, $ci_ty,$qualification);
    $this->load->view('searchresult',$data);
```

**This is my model **

```
 public function login($per_page=3,$look,$age,$age_to,$age_from,$se_ct,$subsect,$coun_try, $sta_te, $ci_ty,$qualification,$per_pg,$offset)
 {
       $query=$this->db->get('users',$per_pg,$offset);
        return $query->result();
 }
     public function message_count()
    {
        return $this->db->count_all("SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE  

if('$se_ct'!='',sect =  '$se_ct' AND if('$subsect' !='',subsect =  '$subsect',subsect like  '%%'),sect like  '%%' AND subsect like  '%%')
AND
IF( '$coun_try' !='', country =  '$coun_try'
AND 
if('$sta_te' !='', state =  '$sta_te'
AND  
if('$ci_ty' !='',city =  '$ci_ty',city like  '%%'),state LIKE  '%%'
AND city LIKE  '%%'), country LIKE  '%%'
AND state LIKE  '%%'
AND city LIKE  '%%' ) 
AND age >=  '$age_from'
AND age <=  '$age_to'
AND 
IF('$qualification' !='',qualification =  '$qualification',  qualification LIKE  '%%' ) 
And gender = '$look'
And status='1'");
    }
```

I am new to ci framework thing is that iam trying to put pagination on my result page in abeobe mentioned way when i do so iam getting error unsupported operands \libraries\pagination.php  so request you to help me
Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in `H:\xampp\htdocs\kkci\system\libraries\Pagination.php on line 124` is the error what iam getting

Comment: Can you put the exact error in the question? : )

Comment: i have put the error at last line of the question

Comment: Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in H:\xampp\htdocs\kkci\system\libraries\Pagination.php on line 124 is the error what iam getting

Comment: The reason you are getting the above error is because `count_all()` expects a table name not a query. Then that error is getting passed through to the pagination library where it is expecting an integer, because it isn't an integer it can't divide by it so it throws this error.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that you are assigning an **array** instead of a **number** into       `$config['total_rows']`

You get this value by calling the login function in your model.

```
$total=$this->searchresultss->login($per_pg,$offset,$per_page,$look,$age, 
$age_to,$age_from,$se_ct,$subsect,$coun_try,$sta_te, $ci_ty, $qualification);
```

then you assign it `$config['total_rows'] = $total;`

However in your model the function is written to return an array:

```
  public function login($per_page=3,$look,$age,$age_to,$age_from,$se_ct,
  $subsect,$coun_try, $sta_te, $ci_ty,$qualification,$per_pg,$offset)
     {
           $query=$this->db->get('users',$per_pg,$offset);
            return $query->result(); //this is an array that is returned
     }
```

To fix this, I believe you can assign the count of the resultset to the total_rows variable:

```
$config['total_rows'] = count($total);
```

Answer (score 0):

in your model do this code

```
 function message_count()
 {
     $q=$this->db-get('tbl_name');
     return $q->num_rows();

  }//now your code in count was correct, or if you want to query your sql syntax the code below
 function message_count()
 {
     $q= $this->db->query("SELECT *
         FROM users
         WHERE  

         if('$se_ct'!='',sect =  '$se_ct' AND if('$subsect' !='',subsect =  '$subsect',subsect like  '%%'),sect like  '%%' AND subsect like  '%%')
         AND
         IF( '$coun_try' !='', country =  '$coun_try'
         AND 
         if('$sta_te' !='', state =  '$sta_te'
         AND  
         if('$ci_ty' !='',city =  '$ci_ty',city like  '%%'),state LIKE  '%%'
         AND city LIKE  '%%'), country LIKE  '%%'
         AND state LIKE  '%%'
         AND city LIKE  '%%' ) 
         AND age >=  '$age_from'
         AND age <=  '$age_to'
         AND 
         IF('$qualification' !='',qualification =  '$qualification',  qualification LIKE  '%%' ) 
         And gender = '$look'
         And status='1'");

         return $q->num_rows();

   }
```

after that, do the code below for pagination

```
 public function login($per_page=3,$look,$age,$age_to,$age_from,$se_ct,$subsect,$coun_try, $sta_te, $ci_ty,$qualification,$per_pg,$offset)
  {
      $query=$this->db->get('users',$per_pg,$offset);
       return $query; //don't append the ->result() in the return of of this code when using pagination
  }
```

in your controller

```
$data['records']=$this->model_name->login($parameters here);
$this->load->view('view_name',$data);
```

in your view do this code

```
    <?php 
          echo $this->table->generate($records);
          echo $this->pagination->create_links();

     ?>
```

hope it will solve your problem

Comment: how can you call the login?

Comment: Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to int